# Is there a function to highlight another stat/point/column while hovering element on Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, web, charts, highcharts, hover

I'm setting up highcharts and want to highlight both two columns/serie/point when I'm hovering in one.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dybtupjc/6/

Researched the web and found that I can use mouseOver & out to handle the element, but I can only handle one, not all of the stats of the series (which is what I need: hover one, and also the other on the other corner)

Tried this, but didn't work..

```
 this.chartConfig.series = [{type: 'column',name: 'Dh',data: dataPoll,point: {
           //events of highcharts
            events: {
           // on mouse over
                mouseOver: function () {
                     var number;
           // loop through all the values that the chart has
                    for(var i = 0; dataPoll.length > i; i++){
           // this.y is the value formatted on the charted and provide in the mouseOver function
                        if(dataPoll[i] == this.y) {
                            console.log("Match", dataPoll[i])
                            console.log("Number", i)
           // And since there are 12 categories (columns), I add 6 to the hover (which is for testing the first numbers, higher numbers will definitely not work), so it can highlight the upper column
                            var number = i + 6;
                            console.log("Sum", number)

                            $scope.setColorSeries(number);
                        }
                    }
           // This is actual valid code, it updates the color of the column under the cursor. Maybe there is a function to call like: this.data[6].update(....)
                    this.update({
                        color: '#000',
                        colorThis: this.color,
                        numberExtrem: number + 6
                    });

                },
                mouseOut: function () {
                    console.log("out mouse!", this)
                    this.update({
                        color: this.colorThis
                    });
                }
            }
        }}];
```

Now, what I want is this:

[image]

It should work like this:

[image]
But the actual output is that I'm hovering the column under the cursor, and I need to highlight both cursor and other column (which it will be its counterpart)

This is the fiddle I uploaded. 
The column under the arrow needs to be black as well.

[image]

And I have a question, how could as well add and arrow between both two columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use point events like `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` to get the actual hovering point and based on its category (in a polar chart it is column angle) calculate an opposite point category which allows you to get this point object and set **hover** state on it. When `mouseOut` events occur set **normal (empty string)** state again using the same approach:

**JS:**

```
point: {
  events: {
    mouseOver: function() {
      setNextPointState(this, 'hover');
    },
    mouseOut: function() {
      setNextPointState(this, '');
    }
  }
}

function setNextPointState(point, state) {
  var series = point.series,
    category = point.category,
    nextPointCategory = category - 180,
    index,
    nextPoint;

  nextPointCategory = (nextPointCategory < 0) ? 360 + nextPointCategory : nextPointCategory;
  nextPointCategory = (nextPointCategory > 360) ? nextPointCategory - 360 : nextPointCategory;

  index = series.xData.indexOf(nextPointCategory);

  if (index !== -1) {
    nextPoint = series.data[index];
    nextPoint.setState(state);
  }
}
```

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bn5wc80p/

> And I have a question, how could as well add an arrow between both
>   two columns?

You can use **vector series** type. If you want to highlight arrows as well use the same approach as with columns. Check the demo and code posted below.

**CSS:**

```
.highcharts-vector-series {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Column',
    data: [8, 7, 3, 4, 9, 4, 7, 3],
    pointPlacement: 'between',
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          setNextPointState(this, 'hover');
          setArrowsState(this, 'green');
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          setNextPointState(this, '');
          setArrowsState(this, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)');
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    type: 'vector',
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
    rotationOrigin: 'start',
    vectorLength: 50,
    lineWidth: 4,
    data: [
      [0, 0, 10, 205],
      [0, 0, 10, 250],
      [0, 0, 10, 295],
      [0, 0, 10, 340],
      [0, 0, 10, 25],
      [0, 0, 10, 70],
      [0, 0, 10, 115],
      [0, 0, 10, 160]
    ]
  }]


function setNextPointState(point, state) {
  var series = point.series,
    category = point.category,
    nextPointCategory = category - 180,
    index,
    nextPoint;

  nextPointCategory = (nextPointCategory < 0) ? 360 + nextPointCategory : nextPointCategory;
  nextPointCategory = (nextPointCategory > 360) ? nextPointCategory - 360 : nextPointCategory;

  index = series.xData.indexOf(nextPointCategory);

  if (index !== -1) {
    nextPoint = series.data[index];
    nextPoint.setState(state);
  }
}

function setArrowsState(point, color) {
  var series = point.series,
    arrowSeries = series.chart.series[1],
    category = point.category,
    arrowDir = category + 180 + 25,
    nextArrowDir = arrowDir + 180,
    index,
    nextIndex,
    arrow,
    nextArrow;

  arrowDir = (arrowDir > 360) ? arrowDir - 360 : arrowDir;
  nextArrowDir = (nextArrowDir > 360) ? nextArrowDir - 360 : nextArrowDir;

  index = arrowSeries.directionData.indexOf(arrowDir);
  nextIndex = arrowSeries.directionData.indexOf(nextArrowDir);

  if (index !== -1 && nextIndex !== -1) {
    arrow = arrowSeries.data[index];
    nextArrow = arrowSeries.data[nextIndex];

    arrow.update({
        color: color
    });

    nextArrow.update({
        color: color
    });
  }
}
```

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.vector 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgkd01q8/

Comment: Really impressive answer., Wojciech. Many thanks for your time; the answer solves the problem.

Comment: How do you make the arrows work so neat with no 8, but 12 columns? I'm trying and it gets messy in the hover. Tried to set the degrees but no luck, https://jsfiddle.net/c28yhLd5/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AhlwUJU.png see the arrows? the hover also doesn't work. except one. strange..

Comment: To make it works with 12 arrows you have to change degrees of each vector and modify the `setArrowsState` function to calculate arrows direction properly. I modified the function and now you can pass an arrow deviation as the third parameter (deviation is equal to 15 degrees for 12 columns). Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fse3k84n/.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't reply; I need to say thank you!  that really helped! (: